# How does NHibernate achieve assignment of a Func<T> parameter.

Tags: c#, nhibernate, system.reflection

Given something like:

```
Post posts = null;
Author author = null;
blog = session.QueryOver<Blog>()
              .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
              .JoinAlias(x => x.Posts, () => posts)
              .JoinAlias(() => posts.Author, () => author)
              .SingleOrDefault();
```

In NHibernate, the above value can be to variables passed into the 2nd argument of the `JoinAlias`

I've tried to figure this out and the closest I get is casting the Body to `MemberExpression` followed by casting the expression to `ConstantExpression` but that creates `.Value` which is readonly, using reflection to assign the member doesn't modify the reference passed in.

How does NH achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not.

This is just syntax. Nothing is assigned neither to `posts` nor to `author`. Those variables are here only to allow using them as aliases in later restrictions, such as in following example taken from [here](/a/5420791/1178314):

> ```
> Cat catAlias = null;
> Kitten kittenAlias = null;
> IQueryOver<Cat,Cat> catQuery =
>     session.QueryOver<Cat>(() => catAlias)
>         .JoinAlias(() => catAlias.Kittens, () => kittenAlias)
>         .Where(() => kittenAlias.Name == "Tiddles");
> ```

It allows `QueryOver` to translate all that to a working SQL query. (I guess actually HQL first, which gets then converted to SQL.) But after execution, you should find your variables untouched, and still `null`.